# How to maintain client side time and server side time in synch in a spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Currently I am facing an issue with datetime in my spring boot project:

I am getting data from UI as:

```
     projectStartDate: "2020-07-15"
```

When I am saving the data in DB, it's getting stored as 2020-07-14. My Microsoft SQL Server is in USA and i am accessing the application from India. Here is my code:

Entity class:

```
     import java.util.Date
     @Column(name = "project_start_date")
     private Date projectStartDate;
```

Pojo Class:

```
       import java.util.Date;
       private Date projectStartDate;
```

And this is what I am doing in my service:

```
      dataToSave.setProjectStartDate(projectMasterData.getProjectStartDate());
```

The problem is when I am entering date 2020-07-15 from UI, but in db it's getting saved as 2020-07-14.
I want to make it as if someone accessing the application from australia, the date should get saved as it's entered in UI like if I entered the date as '2020-07-15', it should save a '2020-07-15', if someone else from USA is accessing the application and trying to get the data of the saved object it should show the USA date of '2020-07-15'.

Can someone help me here please. I am stuck here for hours. Thank you

Comment: Any chance you can migrate from the legacy `java.util.Date` class to the modern `java.time.LocalDate` class? If not, can you use `String` instead of `java.util.Date`?

Comment: If I change to java.time.LocalDate, will this work for all the scenario as I mentioned in my question. Thank you for your support

Comment: Yes LocalDate should "just work" since it's literally just a date: year-month-day. The problem with the legacy Date class is that it represents an instant in time, which may have happened on different days depending on the time zone.

Comment: While changing my existing `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate`, it's throwing error **ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The conversion from date to BINARY is unsupported** as I already have date data in db which are stored as java.util.Date